# operands to ?: have different types, downcast du subclass

Tags: c++, c++17

Code with issue:

```
class A {
    public:
    int i = 2;
};

class B : public A {};
class C : public A {};

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    
    auto x = a.i==2 ? c:b;
}
```

What confuses me, is that when I replace either `c` or`b` with `a`, it seems to recognize that they share a class and will downcast appropriately. So what do I have to do to make this happen here too? I want to avoid an explicit cast to not clutter up the code, but is there any other way?

Comment: You can't "downcast" if it's not a pointer. These types could conceivably have an entirely different stack footprint.

Comment: @tadman You can upcast `B` or `C` to `A`, and it would result in [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing). The interesting part of this question is that the type inference engine isn't able to find a common type. My instinct tells me that [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) (whose rules are similar to the `?:` operator) may be helpful reading material, but I'm not certain why this doesn't work.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo interestingly, `std::common_type<C, B>` doesn't produce a `type` trait: https://godbolt.org/z/dWrqo3vfh

Comment: @SilvioMayolo that's interesting

Comment: Interesting, thanks! Are there any good solutions besides a cast and an if-else expression?